# Multiple datasets with one data value chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Im trying to create a line chart with multiple datasets but with only one data value inside, its posible? Because i tried a lot of modes but always i get undefined in the options, or all the data always in one column.

My code example is the following

```
const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [65]
    },
    {
      label: 'My Second dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [86]
    },
    {
      label: 'My Third dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [95]
    }
  ]
};
```

and i get this

[Problem in the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiRul.png)

But i want to order the first data of the dataset in the first label

Ex: Junuary : 65
    February : 86
    March : 95

[Here is an image that what im looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Jj9.png)

Any one have any idea? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect points from different datasets into a single line. The only way I can think to do it is to simply include each of the data values into a single data set shown below

```
const data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
      hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      data: [65, 86, 95]
    }
  }
```

If you wouldn't mind explaining why you need these in separate datasets, I might be able to help further